# SPARQL CONSTRUCT+INSERT

Tags: sparql, graphdb

I have an XMLHttpRequest with which I call a SPARQL query.

This should create a triple with a UUID and send the UUID back.
How do I correctly formulate this query?

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX schem: <http://schema.org/>
PREFIX rd: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
CONSTRUCT {
    <myns:url> <schem:url> ?s
}
INSERT {GRAPH <file:///home/pi/python_rdf/models.ttl>
    {
    ?s ?p ?o.
    }
WHERE
    { SELECT ?s ?p ?o
      WHERE
      {
        BIND(UUID() AS ?s).
        BIND($p AS ?p).
        BIND($o AS ?o).
      }
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your support

Comment: I do not understand your question. You can't "combine" both. I also do not understand why you would do that. You have to run the INSERT query first, then run the CONSTRUCT query

Comment: The reason is:
I also use SPARQL in GraphDB to generate the UUID together with the parameters passed. I need the generated UUID to be able to process it further.

Comment: You could not mix update with construct/select in a single sparql expression. One way to achieve what you are after is to also pass some unique `$key` along the `$p` and `$o` and associate the generated UUID with it within the update. Then lookup the association with that known key to fetch the UUID, e.g add also `?s <urn:associatedWith> $key` in the update and fetch it with `?uuid <urn:associatedWith> <the-value-that-has-been-bound-to $key>` in the subsequent select/construct operation ...

Comment: OK, understood

Thank you for your efforts